# Facial recognition algorithms Windows form to Web surface API on cloud?

Tags: visual-studio, cloud, emgucv, face-recognition

I have developed a bunch of algorithms on facial recognition using VC# 10 and Emgucv and now I am supposed to export that on cloud through an web API. I don't really want to rewrite the entire code and I am hoping there is a very flexible way of incorporating all the modules I have developed into a single web api to be deployed on azure. I have tried converting them into dlls and running them under xbap. This is the route I want to avoid. Deeply appreciated if you could respond to my query.